# Spring boot admin shows status of gateway server down

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I develop a micro services environment.It is developed by the spring cloud.

The gateway server has been developed by the Zuul and has secured by X.509 certificate authentication(mutual authentication).

I use spring boot admin for monitoring the micro services.

I already use Spring Cloud Discovery for my applications and i added a DiscoveryClient to Spring Boot Admin Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAdminServer
public class ApiAdminServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiAdminServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring boot admin properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=password
```

Service discovery properties:

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.tags.application=${spring.application.name}
```

Gateway properties:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:tls/keyStore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:tls/trustStore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.client-auth=need
```

The gateway server is shown in spring boot admin panel as an application but its status is down.

How do I config spring boot admin for monitoring https gateway application?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Admin makes a call to `/actuator/health` endpoint to know the application health. Please check if this endpoint is working fine, otherwise, you might need to configure it based on your requirements. 
By default Spring check for a number of health indicators mentioned here:

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#auto-configured-healthindicators

You can configure your own indicator as well, a snippet from documentation:

> ```
> import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
> import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
>
> @Component
> public class MyHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
>
>     @Override
>     public Health health() {
>         int errorCode = check(); // perform some specific health check
>         if (errorCode != 0) {
>             return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
>         }
>         return Health.up().build();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I disable SSL authentication in the application.properties file of gateway :

```
management.server.ssl.enabled=false
```

And ignore actuator url path in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class of gateway:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/actuator/health/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .x509()
                .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/**");
    }
```

But be careful , this solution expose important health info of the gateway server for all request.